# Vuforia's take picture slow

Tags: android, vuforia

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-can-i-capture-ar-view

This takes about 30 seconds on my phone to take the picture, how can i speed it up ?

Comment: Basically this is the way to do it - I suggest you try to isolate which part takes most of the time - the pixel grabbing? the saving? Also, what phone did you try it on?

Comment: @yakobom it's in the for loop that run the pixels. Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S6, Android 6

Comment: If it is the same loop as in the link, then it is the minimal you can do - and you are copying quite a lot of pixels...Maybe you can take a smaller portion of the screen?